# Getting text from text element that has overflowing content only returns the visible segment of the text

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I have an SVG containing several groups with a text element and just a bit of text. That text element is set to match the size of its parent, which can sometimes be somewhat small. This occasionally results in a text element that contains more text than it can fit, so it naturally overflows.

I have a loop that cycles through all of these groups to read the text. When it comes across a text element that’s overflown, it only returns the text that’s visible.

In the below example, `theTile` is the group. Also, I’m using [SVG.js](http://svgjs.com/).

```
// If there is a text node in the SVG, collect the details from
// the content and delete it. If there isn't, move on.
const textNode = theTile.select('text');

// Check for a text node. If it exists, collect the content
// for use in positioning for the group.
let groupCoordinates;
const textNodeCount = textNode.members.length;

if (textNodeCount) {
    const tileTextRaw = textNode.last().text();
    … do some stuff with this text …
}
```

`tileTextRaw` ends up returning “name:Peristyle_5”. The full text inside of that text element is actually “name:Peristyle_5-top:162-left:1349-width:50-height:75”

For a visual example, here is the text element I’m trying to read within the SVG:

[image]

This is the SVG I’m working with:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="75" viewBox="0 0 50 75">
 <title>Peristyle_5</title>
 <g id="Peristyle_5">
  <g>
   <rect id="background-2" data-name="background" width="50" height="75" fill="#7facc7"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="translate(9.726 21.76)" font-size="15" font-family="OperatorMonoSSm-Book, Operator Mono SSm">nam<tspan x="0" y="18">e:P</tspan><tspan x="0" y="36">eri</tspan></text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is this `.select()`, `.members` and `last().text()`? Are you using a library?

Comment: I’m sorry. I should have mentioned and added a tag. I’m using SVG.js. I’ll update the question.

Comment: Is that picture a true represntaion of the rendered SVG? In particular, are these linebreaks rendered? SVG has no automatic linebreak like HTML, it depends on child `<tspan>` elements for that. Please show the code or DOM view for the SVG.

Comment: Added the code for the SVG. Yes, the image above is a screenshot of the actual SVG.

Comment: Well, not of that one. Your code produces [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELJKGR), here magnified by a factor 10. (Magnification does not change the layout.)

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: This is geting a bit ridiculous, isn't it? Every time something changes about the SVG we are talking about, but you give no explanation at all why it changes.

Comment: The only change from the previous SVG to the current is the text size. You won’t see the exact same result on your end because it requires the font Operator Mono ScreenSmart Book to be installed on your system. Otherwise I believe the issue at hand should be apparent.

Comment: No, because you are obviously using some sort of program logic to produce line breaks. They do not happen by themself, and there is no method in SVG.js that would do so. I suspect you are using a plugin, but are not telling about it. I've tried to decuce it from its behavior, but can't find one yet on Github that would break words like it appears to happen here. Bottom line: There is no overflow in the sense that HTML would have it. The plugin will have removed the non-fitting text. If you're lucky, its still there for retrieval like https://github.com/NightPhoenix/svg.textflow.js does.

Comment: No plugins. This is an SVG exported directly from Illustrator.

Comment: Then you should ask about what Illustrator does. (Sorry, not my area of expertise.) As I said, the overflowing text is no longer in the markup.